# Can I autowire a singleton bean inside a controller class in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

- I am trying to call a singleton bean from a controller
- this bean is already initialized
- But when called from controller;controller is
  creating new bean instead of using existing bean

Comment: show us the relevant code & configuration and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Prototype scoped bean in a singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton)