# Spring: Choosing constructor while Autowiring a Component

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired, spring-bean

I've a Component as follows:

```
@Component
class A(){
    private s;
    public A(){}
    public A(String s){this.s=s;}
}
```

Here is the other class Where I'm auto wiring the above class:

```
@Component
class B(){

    @Autowire
    private A a;
}
```

In the above autowiring, I need to use the parameterized constructor. How can I pass the constructor args?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-declaring-a-bean

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not via `@Autowired` in `B` but there are other ways to do it:

#### Wire the parameter into `A`'s constructor:

One constructor is annotated with `@Autowired` [because](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation):

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, the @Autowired constructor is no longer
>   necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor. If several
>   constructors are available, at least one must be annotated to teach
>   the container which one it has to use.

```
@Component
class A(){
    private s;
    public A(){}

    @Autowired
    public A(@Value("${myval}") String s){this.s=s;}
}
```

#### Expose `A` as a `@Bean`

Straight from [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public A a(@Value("${myval}") String s) {
        return new A(s);
    }
}
```

#### Construct `A` in `B` using an initialization callback

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)

```
@Component
class B(){
    private A a;
    @Value("${myval}")
    private String myval;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        a = new A(myval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of prototype bean which I think you require in your case. @Component will create a singleton bean and changing it in one place will change in all parent classes where this was injected.

You need to understand how to inject a prototype bean in singleton bean.
Follow this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165971/949912

Answer (score -1):

Just use setters instead of constructor. 
If you want to create object by yourself with **new** keyword then this object will not be managed by container.

Comment: Calling a setter will change all references of the singleton bean.

Comment: No one said that bean should be singleton or prototype.