# How @prototype scope helps in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, singleton, prototype

I was given a single threaded application and asked to make it multithreaded. There are many singleton instances used.

I know that when a singleton instance is shared between multiple threads, all the variables of that instance will be shared between multiple threads.

For example, there is a count variable, it is a singleton instance variable. My idea is that each thread should increment the 'count' .Each thread increments only once. So the counter should be 1. If I increment this variable of the shared object, all the threads will get that value. So when the 2nd thread does it, the value will not be 1, but 2. For the nth thread that increments it, the value it sees will be n, not 1.

Inorder to prevent this, I used a prototype scope on that class. Now I will get a new object for each thread and the counter will remain 1 for each thread.

This is how I thought I would use prototype scope. Does this makes sense? I gave an example for counter, there are many, many such variables of different types in that shared instance. 
Is my use of prototype justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a local variable for the above-said purpose, it doesn't have to be an instance variable.

> In order to prevent this, I used a prototype scope on that class. Now
>   I will get a new object for each thread and the counter will remain 1
>   for each thread.
>
> This is how I thought I would use prototype scope. Does this makes
>   sense?

This makes sense, but only thing is, I don't see a case for an instance variable, as I said before, you can easily pull this off with a local variable.
Be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton) with a prototype scoped bean injected into a singleton scoped bean.
[Spring Prototype scoped bean in a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton)

Comment: This is not just about  a single variable 'Counter' but there are many such variables.

Comment: if those variables doesnt need to be shared across different threads, it can be local variables (variables which have lifecycle contained within a method)

Comment: @hars If this answered your question, please accept it, that will help fellow SO users

Comment: I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: minimum reputation is for "upvoting". To accept an answer there is no minimum rep requirement. There is tick mark right below the "Votes" of answer which will turn green on click.