# How to make prototype beans inside singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, factory

I need to be able to create new bean instance - not on every call to method like in `proxyMode=*`, but only when needed (eg. to call `.getObject()`).

I know that there is `ObjectFactory` and `ServiceFactory`, but problem with this is that I cannot define factories in java config, but have to use hardcoded string inside bean. So this is what I want to achieve:

```
@Configuration
    class Config {
        @Bean
        public MessageListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory() {
            MessageListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory = new MessageListenerContainerFactory();
            listenerContainerFactory.setMessageListener(rabbitProcessor());
            return listenerContainerFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public MessageListener rabbitProcessor() {
            return new RabbitProcessor();
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public MessageListener notThisOne() {
            return new NotThisOne();
        }
    }

    class MessageListenerContainerFactory {

        private MessageListener messageListener;

        public void setMessageListener(MessageListener messageListener) {
            this.messageListener = messageListener;
        }

        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer createListenerContainer(){
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer setMessageListener= new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();

            //THIS HERE IS NEEDED!!!
            Object needed = SPRINGCONTEXT.GETBEANNAMEOF(this.messageListener).getObject();


            listenerContainer.setMessageListener(needed);
            return setMessageListener;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will this approach work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton ?

Comment: No, since I would need to use @Autowired annotation inside MessageListenerContainerFactory, and I also have 2 beans of same type (rabbitProcessor and notThisOne)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with @Qualifier annotation.

Ref - http://zetcode.com/articles/springbootqualifier/

```
@Bean
        @Qualifier("rabbitProcessor")
        @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public MessageListener rabbitProcessor() {
            return new RabbitProcessor();
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("notThisOne")
        @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public MessageListener notThisOne() {
            return new NotThisOne();
        }
```

Then you can create object by calling getBean() on applicationContext whenever you need like ..

```
applicationContext.getBean("rabbitProcessor");
//or
applicationContext.getBean("notThisOne");
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like a reasonable solution. I would use `listenerContainerFactory.setMessageListenerBeanName("rabbitProcessor");` to notify `MessageListenerContainerFactory` what is the name of the bean. I actually don't need qualifiers in that case, since name will actually be the same as the method name. The only problem here is that I have to hard-code string during bean initialization.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding inside MessageListenerContainerFactory, pass parameter to your MessageListenerContainerFactory. Ref - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-and