# Injecting Dependencies to a Singleton class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a singleton instance defined like this:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {

    }

    public Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now, due to some changes, this class has to depend on a few(3) dependencies. So, those dependencies have to be **injected** here.

How can we achieve dependency injection for a Singleton class designed this way?

The problem is that there are already a lot of callers on `Singleton.getInstance()` and hence cannot make the getInstance method to accept the dependencies.

P.S: I understood using Singletons are not always a cleaner way :)
(This is existing code and I have to live with it:))

P.S: I'm using Guice for dependency injection.

Comment: which dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: Either you have to be able to make the dependencies available by static methods too; or you have to bite the bullet and pass the singleton instance to all the places currently invoking `getInstance()`.

Comment: @PillHead Using guice

Comment: @AndyTurner What do you mean exactly my making the dependencies available by static methods? Anyways when the client calls the static getInstance(), the others dependencies will be left uninitialized

Comment: please edit the question to specify that this is a Guice application

Comment: Singleton pattern violates the Dependency Inversion Principle, and that's why this pattern doesn't mix and match with Dependency Injection. You should refactor away from this pattern and instead inject it as dependency into the constructors of its consumers. You can use the _Singleton lifestyle_ to ensure that only one instance of it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your class as a dependency while keeping the same API for clients.
With Spring for example :

```
@Component
public class Singleton {

  private Foo foo;
  private Bar bar;
  private Any any;

  // inject dependencies 
  @Autowired
  // annotation not required in recent Spring versions
  public Singleton (Foo foo, Bar bar, Any any){
     this.foo = foo;
     this.bar = bar;
     this.any = any;
  }

  public Singleton getInstance() {
      return this;
  }
}
```

And from the client side you can either inject the bean or retrieve it from the bean container if the client class is not a bean.

Example of accessing from a bean class :

```
public class SingletonClient{

    @Autowired
    private Singleton singleton;

    public void foo(){
        singleton.getInstance().method();
    } 
}
```

---

Idea to avoid changes from the client classes.
Disclaimer : I don't promote this way as it is both counter-intuitive, error prone and above all maintain the technical debt  of the static access for the singleton.
It is acceptable as a temporary solution but a refactoring of the exiting code should really be performed as soon as possible.

So the idea is storing the bean instance in the static field during the constructor invocation.
In this way, `Singleton.getInstance()` return the bean.

```
@Component
public class Singleton {

    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;
    private Any any;

    private static Singleton instance;

    // inject dependencies
    @Autowired
    // annotation not required in recent Spring versions
    public Singleton(Foo foo, Bar bar, Any any) {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.bar = bar;
      this.any = any;
      instance = this;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
      return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: But this requires changing all the clients (as they are calling the static getInstance method). I was looking if there is any other way to do it other than making the singleton class a normal dependency/class

Comment: I assume that it should not be a important refactoring (replacing `Singleton.getInstance()` by `singleton.getInstance()`. A singleton with a static access will have a hard time becoming a dependency. Static and dependency injection don't work at all in the same way.

Comment: I agree with your point. So you say there is no way to add injectable dependencies to such a Singleton class with such a static method without changing the way clients call it (Here the Singleton itself has to be passed/injected to each of the clients)?

Comment: I don't say that it is not possible but it will be a counter intuitive and error-prone approach.  I edited with that. It is done in Spring to keep consistent with my initial answer but you could do exactly the same thing with Guice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
public class Singleton {

    private DependencyClass1 dependency1;

    private DependencyClass2 dependency2;

    private DependencyClass3 dependency3;

    private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton(
            new DependencyClass1(...),
            new DependencyClass2(...),
            new DependencyClass3(...)
    );

    private Singleton(
            DependencyClass1 dependency1,
            DependencyClass2 dependency2,
            DependencyClass3 dependency3
    ) {
        this.dependency1 = dependency1;
        this.dependency2 = dependency2;
        this.dependency3 = dependency3;
    }

    public Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

It is the same as worked any IOC Container.

---

If all injected dependencies have a singleton scope you can do this, otherwise you need to create instance of injected class every time when it needed.

There is example of injection Protype Beans Into Singleton Beans:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165971/3058413

Comment: There's not much point in doing it like that: you're just repeating the `DependencyClass1 dependency1` in lots of places. `private DependencyClass1 = new DependencyClass1(...); /* ... */ INSTANCE = new Singleton();` is equivalent and shorter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this as I can't `hardcode` a concrete dependency as it has to be injected.

Comment: I think that non-default constructor obviously shows that this class depends on some other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @Singleton annotation in Guice to tell the injector to only create one instance that is shared across your application.  You can then inject the dependencies in the usual way by either annotating the variables or a chosen constructor

```
    @Singleton
    public class Singleton {

      @Inject // Choose to put the annotation here OR on a constructor, not both
      private Foo foo;

      @Inject // only put this constructor here if you don't annotate the variable
      public Singleton (Foo foo){
         this.foo = foo;
      }

      public Singleton getInstance() {
          return this;
      }

...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring you can achieve dependency injection even without a public constructor. Just mark the dependencies @Autowired. Spring will inject them via reflection. :)