# How to ask for Prototype bean in Spring service class without applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, dependency-injection

I have a component defined with prototype scope. I want to use that component in my service class. I want spring to provide me a new instance of that Bean everytime I call for it.

Component Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ProtoTypeBean {
  //.. Field variables
}
```

Service Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ServiceClass {
    ProtoTypeBean prototypeBean;
    ArrayList<ProtoTypeBean> prototypeBeans;
    public void demoMethod(ArrayList<String> someArrayList) {

        for(var singleString: someArrayList) {
            prototypeBean.setFieldValue(singleString);

            prototypeBeans.add(prototypeBean);              
        }
        System.out.println(prototypeBeans.toString());
    }
}
```

By using this configuration, I am getting the same instance of ProtoTypeBean in my prototypeBeans ArrayList. The question is, how would I make Spring understand to give me a new instance of prototypeBean every time I am calling it into the foreach loop?
I found I can use ApplicationContext.getBean() to get a new instance of the Bean in foreach loop but I also heard that it's a bad practice. So kindly help me with the best practice.

Comment: You have the same object cause it is only once injected into this class so only one new instance is created

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Prototype scoped bean in a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165507/spring-prototype-scoped-bean-in-a-singleton)

Comment: A scoped proxy won't work as that will give you a new instance for each method call you do. Probably hardly what you want. Instead you can inject a `Provider` or `ObjectFactory` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [`ObjectProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) to lazily get the result you want. However the first prototype scoped bean will not be represented in the list of beans as, well they are prototype scoped.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ServiceClass {

    private final ObjectProvider<ProtoTypeBean> provider;

    public void demoMethod(ArrayList<String> someArrayList) {
        PrototypeBean pb = provider.getIfUnique();
        for(var singleString: someArrayList) {
            pb.setFieldValue(singleString);
            pb.add(prototypeBean);              
        }
        System.out.println(prototypeBean.toString());
    }
}
```

Also if you don't need all the dependency injection, proxy creation etc. for your object then why bother. There is nothing wrong with just the `new` keyword in a Spring application. Not everything has to be managed by Spring.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing knowledge

Comment: very fine, especially the new-hint

Answer (score 1):

Set up your prototype bean similar to this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ProtoTypeBean {

  final private String param;

  public ProtoTypeBean(final String p) {
    this.param = p;
  }
}
```

Now, in your service class use a [`BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) to create the beans for you:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ServiceClass {

  private final BeanFactory factory;
  private List<ProtoTypeBean> prototypeBeans;

  @Autowired
  public ServiceClass(final BeanFactory f) {
    this.factory = f;
  }

  public void demoMethod(List<String> someArrayList) {

    this.prototypeBeans = someArrayList
        .stream()
        .map(param -> factory.getBean(ProtoTypeBean.class, param))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently. I am sure there must be a better way than mine, but this is how I did it:

```
public class ServiceClass {

ArrayList<ProtoTypeBean> prototypeBeans = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

public void demoMethod(ArrayList<String> someArrayList) {
    for(var singleString: someArrayList) {
        //magic is in below line.. getting a bean from ApplicatioContext.
        ProtoTypeBean prototypeBean= ctx.getBean("protoTypeBean"); //Or ctx.getBean(ProtoTypeBean.class);
        prototypeBean.setFieldValue(qBean.getFieldValue());

        prototypeBeans.add(prototypeBean);              
    }
    System.out.println(prototypeBeans.toString());
}
```

This way, Spring container always give you a new instance. And it is totally managed by Spring container.

The way you tried it, I tried that as well, but it would always inject one instance at the time of autowiring, hence defeating the purpose of prototyping.

You could have gone the route of using `new` Keyword. But then that is just regular Java instantiation and *I think* that new instance is not managed by Spring because it is annotated with `@Component` instead of `@Configuration`. I could be wrong here though.

Comment: Asking ApplicationContext to provide beans is a possible solution but as I already mentioned on my issue, it is a bad practice.
Best way to achieve this is by using getIfUnique() method of ObjectProvider<T> class. Thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: @RitamDas I looked at the other two answers. It increased my knowledge and I am thankful I participated in this question. Thank you for asking thought provoking question.