# @Autowired not working inside a runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a runnable task where i am trying to Autowire  field but when i do it the task doesn't run .
When i Autowire the field outside the runnable it works fine . Why is this happening ? Also is there any other cleaner way to get new instances of a autowired field inside runnable other than Autowiring it inside  ?

Here's my runnable method `

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {

                @Autowired
                ICruxPanelClientService CruxPanelClientService;

                public void run (){
            CruxPanelClientService.setCruxWebServiceBaseURL("http://10.41.181.23:8080");
            CronCruxModel m = new CronCruxModel();
            m = model1.get(model_var);
            System.out.println("EXECUTING");
            System.out.println(m.getService_status() + " ---------EXEexecution");
            System.out.println(m.getCat_name() + "Executing Name ");
        //  time = m.getService_time();
            UpdateCategoryRequest updateCategoryRequest = new UpdateCategoryRequest();
            CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
            categoryModel.setColor(m.getCat_color());
            categoryModel.setIcon(m.getCat_icon());
            categoryModel.setIconWhite(m.getCat_icon_white());
            categoryModel.setName(m.getCat_name());
            categoryModel.setId(m.getCat_id());
            categoryModel.setKey(m.getCat_catkey());
            categoryModel.setIndexOrder(m.getCat_indexOrder());
            updateCategoryRequest.setCategory(categoryModel);
            CruxPanelClientService.updateCategory(updateCategoryRequest);
            GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdRequest request1 = new GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdRequest();    
            request1.setId(m.getCat_id());
            GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdResponse response1 = CruxPanelClientService.getServiceDataIdByCategoryId(request1);
            ArrayList<ServiceModel> service = new ArrayList<ServiceModel>();
            service = response1.getServiceModels();

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
            if(m.getService_order_succ_msg()==null)
            {
                json = new JSONArray();
            }
            else {

                 json = new JSONArray(m.getService_order_succ_msg());
            }
            String message = m.getService_order_succ_msg();

            for (int j=0;j<service.size();j++)
            {   
                UpdateServiceMasterRequest req = new UpdateServiceMasterRequest();
                ServiceModel s = new ServiceModel();
                s=service.get(j);
                ;
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                if(json.length()==0 ) 
                {
                    String ms = null;
                    s.setOrderSuccessMessage(ms);
                    req.setServiceModel(s);

                }

                else {

                    String message1 = json.get(j).toString();

                    if(message1.equals(null) || message1.equals("")) {
                        String ms = null;
                        s.setOrderSuccessMessage(ms);
                        req.setServiceModel(s);

                    }
                    else {
                        s.setOrderSuccessMessage(message1);

                        req.setServiceModel(s);

                    }
                }
                CruxPanelClientService.updateServiceMaster(req);

            }
            m.setService_status("executed");
            UpdateCronCruxRequest q = new UpdateCronCruxRequest();
            q.setCronCruxModel(m);
            CruxPanelClientService.updateCronCrux(q);

                }
            };`
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem is spring doesn't control creation of your runnable. There are couple possible solutions:

1. Put you runnable creation in some service, repository, controller, component or what ever handled by spring:

Example:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private ICruxPanelClientService cruxPanelClientService;

    public Runnable newRunnable() {

        return new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                cruxPanelClientService <- will be visible here and injected
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2. Create runnable as bean with prototype scope

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class Runnableconfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Runnable newRunnbale(final ICruxPanelClientService cruxPanelClientService) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                cruxPanelClientService <- will be visible here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`@Autowire` can't be used for anonymous classes (because you call `new`, not Spring), you can autowire a field in outer class and then use that field inside your `Runnable`.

Or make the `Runnable` a full blown class (not anonymous) and make it a bean (and autowire, e.g. using the `id`)

Comment: If `Runnable` is defined as full blown class, it needs to be declared as bean to make `@Autowire` work, and in this case the bean scope should be `Prototype`. So you need to autowire prototype bean in the singleton bean then, here are some details how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880847/howto-generate-prototype-objects-with-in-a-singleton-bean-using-spring-java-conf/14881193#14881193

Answer (score 3):

Spring does not `@autowire` anything into **unmanaged instances** (instances you create with `new`, in contrast to instances created and managed by Spring).

This leaves you following options:

- `@autowire` the dependency outside and pass it to the `Runnable` (or make it accessible to the `Runnable`).
- create a new class subclassing `Runnable`, and `@autowire` it where you need it.
- Instead of having the dependency injected, look it up (`applicationContext.getBean(..)`) when needing it.

**Be careful with scopes and lazy initialization when using Threads**, as some of the Spring scopes (e.g. "request" or "session" scope) are thread-local bound (e.g. when using a lazy request-scoped dependency in a new Thread, which when executed is no longer associated with the current request).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all mentioned above, maybe it is better to inject the service from outside your runnable and not use `@Autowired` inside your runnable. So in your case:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {

                @Autowired
                ICruxPanelClientService CruxPanelClientService;
```

would become:

```
@Autowired
private ICruxPanelClientService CruxPanelClientService;

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
...
}
```