# Service falling with nullPointer when calling it by name and working when calling rest

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, spring-boot

I have a runnable class

```
public class MissingPartitionsTask implements Runnable {
@Autowired
private PartitionsService partitionsService;

private Schedules schedule;

MissingPartitionsTask(Schedules schedule){
    this.schedule = schedule;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    partitionsService.findAll(schedule.getId());
}
}
```

When I run it, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MissingPartitionsTask.run(MissingPartitionsTask.java:26)
```

This is row 26

```
partitionsService.findAll(schedule.getId());
```

I checked `schedule.getId()`. It's not empty. There are 3 rows in the table with id 1, 2 and 3.

I also have a service

```
@GetMapping("/partitions/{id}")
public List<LocalDate> findAll(@PathVariable long id) {
    return partitionsService.findAll(id);
}
```

It works when I call it using my browser and returns a list of dates.

```
http://localhost:8181/partitions/3
```

Why does `MissingPartitionsTask` not work?

EDIT
My application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

EDIT2

```
@Service
public class SchedulerService {
    @Autowired
    private ScheduleRepository scheduleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)
    public void scheduleAll() {
        scheduleRepository.findAll().forEach(
            schedule -> {
                MissingPartitionsTask missingPartitionsTask = new MissingPartitionsTask(schedule);
                taskExecutor.execute(missingPartitionsTask);
            });
    }

}
```

EDIT3

[Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Does not help. My service is autowired

```
@Autowired
private PartitionsService partitionsService;
```

and annotated

```
@Service
public class PartitionsService {
```

schedule IS NOT NULL. It returns values.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(schedule.getId());
}
```

result `1 2 3`

The service works when I do a GET, it does not work when I try calling it from a thread.

EDIT4

[This helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026330/autowired-not-working-inside-a-runnable)

The problem was that Spring didn't control my runnable. Moving my run method to SchedulerService as

```
private Runnable newRunnable(Schedules schedule) {
        return () -> {
            List<String> missing = partitionsService.findMissing(schedule.getId());
        };
    }
```

And calling it like this

```
taskExecutor.execute(newRunnable(schedule));
```

instead of

```
taskExecutor.execute(missingPartitionsTask);
```

Solved it.

Comment: Is PartitionService annotated as a Component, or Service? And is it in the same package as, or a subpackage of, the Application class?

Comment: @Dave It's annotated as `Service` and is in a subpackage called service.

Comment: @Dave Your link does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run application and not single class as stand alone application for this to work.
As you are using autowire, spring has to initialise this class and then you have to call that function.
If you run this class directly there wont be autowired class available and you will get null pointer exception.

I hope this helps

Comment: I do run it as Application. Otherwise the endpoint `/partitions/3` woudn't work, no? Or what do you mean? Added my application class.

Comment: Can you please post code which starts you thread and you get null pointer?
I got how you run it through endpoint, but when do you get null pointer

Comment: Added as EDIT2.

Comment: MissingPartitionsTask missingPartitionsTask = new MissingPartitionsTask(schedule)

because of new operator this object is created manually and not a bean managed by spring and hence it will not create autowired object

Comment: The problem is not here. When I call `schedule.getId()` from run method it works. The problem is in `partitionsService` it is autowired and the service is annotated, but it's still null.