# SpringBoot : Using @Autowired instance inside Runnable Run method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use an instance of object instantiated through `@Autowire` inside a class with Runnable, but I am getting `Null Pointer Exception`

I went through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026330/autowired-not-working-inside-a-runnable) but all the solution I tried and still its the same problem.

Sharing my code :

```
@Component
public class MyClass{

@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

private String a;
private String b;

public MyClass() {
}
public MyClass(String a, String b) {
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
}
public Runnable newRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           serviceA.innerMethod(a, b);  //got NPE here
        }
     };
  }
}
```

And I am calling this class runnable like this from other class

`executor.submit(new MyClass("abc", "def").newRunnable());`

So, am I doing something wrong, or is there any way where I could use the object

Comment: Whenever you use `new` in any framework with dependency injection (so Spring Boot but also Quarkus, CDI, etc.) *nothing will get injected*. The framework doesn't hook itself in constructors, it calls those constructors when you inject instances of these classes.

Comment: It works like this because you created this instance manually - `new MyClass("abc", "def")`. If you want to inject dependency you need to inject `abc` and `def` as properties and let `Spring` to create `MyClass` instance.

Comment: @MichałZiober The values in the constructor I get at runtime and I need to spin multiple threads with different values, so multiple instance also I need. Is it possible to do that

Comment: @arqam, take a look here how to create a prototype bean with params: [Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped Bean with runtime arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are seeing NPE, coz `ServiceA` is not injected in to your MyClass. And that is becoz you created `MyClass` through `new` keyword i.e `new MyClass("abc", "def")`

Try getting `MyClass` also from container i.e

```
@Autowired MyClass myClass;
```

and use `myClass` in the executor.

```
executor.submit(myClass.newRunnable());
```

Comment: But what if I want to create multiple instances of myClass with different values in the constructor at runtime to pass in the executor.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: - by default Bean scopes are singleton.  But I see your point. I advice you to post a separate Q with the second part of your problem.. that is - `how to get multiple instances of MyClass with different FIELD VALUES when using spring IOC.`. If you do post a Q, plz do leave the link of it here so others viewing this Q will also benefit from it and might even help you.